# getContext blur effect, cant find this.prev('canvas')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

html:

```
<div class="span">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <video autoplay loop muted onloadeddata="loaded(this)">
        <source src="xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
<div class="span">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <video autoplay loop muted onloadeddata="loaded(this)">
        <source src="yyy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

js:

```
function draw(v, c, w, h) {
    if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
    setTimeout(draw, 1, v, c, w, h);
};
function loaded(vid) {
    $(vid).on('play', function() {
      var $this = $(vid).prev('canvas'),//this one dont work?
         $this = $('canvas').get(0),//i dont want this get(x), i need "this"
         cw = Math.floor($this.clientWidth / 1),
         ch = Math.floor($this.clientHeight / 1);
      $this.width = cw;
      $this.height = ch;
      draw(this, $this.getContext("2d"), cw, ch);
    });
};
```

why i cant find "this"???

$this = $(vid).prev('canvas'),//this one dont work?

$this = $('canvas').get(0),//i dont want this get(x), i need "this"

thanks man, help me fix this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrJqwQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev()` returns a jQuery object. What you need is to get the canvas element which you can do with `$(vid).prev('canvas').get(0)` or `$(this).prev('canvas').get(0)`

e.g.

```
function loaded(vid) {
    $(vid).on('play', function() {
      var canvas = $(this).prev('canvas').get(0);
      cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 1),
      ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight / 1);
      canvas.width = cw;
      canvas.height = ch;
      draw(this, canvas.getContext("2d"), cw, ch);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts from this line:

```
<video autoplay loop muted onloadeddata="loaded(this)">
```

`this` here refers to the window object and not the `video` element.

One solution to fix it would be as the following:

html:

```
<div class="span">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <!-- remove "this" here because it won't be used -->
      <video autoplay loop muted onloadeddata="loaded()">
        <source src="xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
<div class="span">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <!-- remove "this" here because it won't be used -->
      <video autoplay loop muted onloadeddata="loaded()">
        <source src="yyy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

js:

```
function draw(v, c, w, h) {
    if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
    setTimeout(draw, 1, v, c, w, h);
};

/*
Instead of "vid" argument use "this" keyword. 
"this" will refer to video element here.
*/
function loaded() {
    $(this).on('play', function() {
      var $this = $(this).prev('canvas'),//this one dont work?
         $this = $('canvas').get(0),//i dont want this get(x), i need "this"
         cw = Math.floor($this.clientWidth / 1),
         ch = Math.floor($this.clientHeight / 1);
      $this.width = cw;
      $this.height = ch;
      draw(this, $this.getContext("2d"), cw, ch);
    });
};
```